# How to avoid inline script when passing MVC model into javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application, content-security-policy

I have the following in my MVC view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.appVm = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
</script>
```

Where `Model` is some arbitrary object.  I need to attach this to the `window` so my JS initialization module has access to the data.

I'm learning about `Content-Security-Policy`, and this is in clear violation due to having an inline script.

What's the proper way to assign a `Model` to `window` without an inline script?

Comment: I constantly have to do the same thing, so i want to know the answer too, obviously you can't include Model inside some script file

Comment: There is no proper way of assigning a Model to window, because that's not something you should be doing. You should be using ajax to retrieve your model separately from the page load, or using ASP.NET MVC's `@Html.*For` helpers to create the form fields necessary to encapsulate your model.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I respectfully disagree.  When loading a `SPA` we don't need to be making two requests - one for the page and another for data - when both resources are coming from the same place.